# Xcode 6 Beta 4 toolchain issue - Can't complie

Tags: xcode, toolchain, xcode6

This error did happened before, I fixed it by deleting derived files, but this time, it won't work anyway. It's rather big project so far written in Swift, but I desperately need to fix this error. Since it's compiler error, there are not much information other than,

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

This is the line above the problem, 4 of these similar error codes..

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither%.asUnsubstituted = bitcast %objc_object* %139 to i64, !dbg !642 LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

Comment: I too have this problem..

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling XCode 6 beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

First, try a clean build. That occasionally fixes issues for me.

Anyway, the beta compiler sometimes segfaults when you're trying to use an unimplemented or buggy feature. It *should* either compile correctly or give you a compiler error (e.g. "Class variables are not yet implemented" or something), but that doesn't always happen.

Look about 2-3 lines above that bottom line you posted and you'll probably see something like "Unable to execute command: Segementation fault: 11" (typed from memory). A line or two above that is usually a line that says what code file/line it broke on (but take that line with a grain of salt). Try and figure out what you've changed in that class since the last error.

Failing that: If you look all the way to the top of the compiler error, there might be a stack trace. Though you're obviously not an Xcode dev, that might give you enough of a hint as to what went wrong to figure out what the offending code line was.

Comment: Thank you, but like what you expected i am not a pro... I edited the question above to show the errors. But still I can't figure out what the problem is. There is no trace of error other than those 4 similar Bitcast errors.